# How to export the Kendo treeview in MVC to PDF file?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

We are using Kendo treeview in MVC, and we have a requirement to export the whole tree view (with all nodes expanded) to a PDF file.

How can we achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the Stackoverflow community . Please specify which version of kendo you are using ?